# want to print $ in html

Tags: php, html

i want to print a input value using html.

input will be like below..

```
<input type='text' name='tr_id' class='form-control' id='tr_id' style='height:35px;width:200px;' value='<?php echo $row['$tr_id'];'>
```

i am using below code to get the required input

```
$field_name='tr_id';
$field_type='text';
$html .= "<input type='".$field_type."' name='".$field_name."' class='form-control' id='".$field_name."' style='height:35px;width:200px;' value='<?php echo $row['".field_name."']'>";
echo $html;
```

but i think i am getting error on value. can you please help how can i print

Comment: var_dump($row); show please.

Comment: Your last field_name variable needs a $ in front of it.

Comment: @theatlasroom   Yes... Plus there is also the `error` of doing `<?php echo $row[...]; ?>` The PHP Opening & closing Tags are the cause of the errors because he is already within an Open PHP Block...  additionally, doing `echo $row[...]` is just illogical as he is also building up an HTML String which he finally echoed in the end as: `echo $html;`

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is not so clear, however it might be logical to assume that you may really have a typo in your PHP Code where you were echoing out the field_name.
Here is a correction on that part.

```
    <?php
        $field_name ='tr_id';
        $field_type ='text';
        $html      .= "<input type='".$field_type."' name='".$field_name."' class='form-control' id='".$field_name."' style='height:35px;width:200px;' value='{$row[$field_name]}' />";
        echo $html;
```

Notice that the line: `$html .= "<input type='".$field_type."' name='".$field_name."' class='form-control' id='".$field_name."' style='height:35px;width:200px;' value='<?php echo $row['".field_name."']'>";`
 has changed to reflect what is presumably what you intended to do: `$html      .= "<input type='".$field_type."' name='".$field_name."' class='form-control' id='".$field_name."' style='height:35px;width:200px;' value='{$row[$field_name]}' />"`

The reason for this is because you are already in PHP Mode so you don't need to do something like `<?php echo $row...?>` within a PHP block... (**meaning: you don't open & close a PHP Block within an already existing PHP Block**) and, in fact, since you are doing `echo $html` it would be pointless to echo anything again within the code that builds up your string. The Point here is that you should rather build-up your String without echoing anything and then finally `echo $html` once you are done building up your HTML String. This way you'd avoid the Errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

try below code..

```
<input type='text' name='tr_id' class='form-control' id='tr_id' style='height:35px;width:200px;' value='<?php echo $row[$tr_id];'>
```

And

```
$field_name='tr_id';
$field_type='text';
$row = array('field_name','test');`enter code here`
$html .= '<input type ="'.$field_type.'" name="'.$field_name.'" class="form-control" id="'.$field_name.'" style="height:35px;width:200px;" value="'.$row["field_name"].'" >';
echo $html;
```